# discovering mySQL port

Tags: mysql, linux

I don't have root and the sysadmin is gone for the day.  Trying to find remote port for mySQL.  So /etc/my.cnf does not have skip-networking enabled and says

```
connect-string="nodeid=2;host=localhost:1186"
```

but 1186 does not seem to be the port at least not for remote connections.

```
-sh-3.2$ netstat -apn | grep mysqld
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=5290 but you should be root.)
```

I also tried

```
-sh-3.2$ netstat -anp | grep -i mysql
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=5290 but you should be root.)
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8720   -                   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     64766511 -                   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     64766258 -                   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     64765669 -                   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     64764151 -                   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     64746846 -                   /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Per Jim Garrison I tried

```
-sh-3.2$ netstat -nat|grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 xxx.xx.xxx.18:80            0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 xxx.xx.xxx.172:80           0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8081                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 xxx.xx.xxx.18:443           0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 xxx.xx.xxx.172:443          0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

ps aux | fgrep mysql   yields

```
root      3802  0.0  0.0  65972  1316 ?        S    Jun02   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/webroot/mysqldata --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --federated --user=mysql
mysql     3902  3.5  0.5 517284 97720 ?        Sl   Jun02 5619:08 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/webroot/mysqldata --user=mysql --federated --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
myusr     24025  0.0  0.0   6024   528 pts/1    S+   21:42   0:00 fgrep mysql
```

Anything else I can try?

Comment: Try `netstat -nat|grep LISTEN`

Comment: @Jim - tried only got tcp results.  Added to post above

Comment: You haven't actually said what happens when you DO try to connect.

Comment: Also, this is off topic for SO.  Voting to move to serverfault.

Comment: @Jim No error.  Just fails to connect.

Comment: I voted to close and move as well.  Thx for help Jim and all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joe H's was correct there was a firewall blocking me.  Sorry for having so many folks try to help for naught.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose

```
ps aux | fgrep mysql
```

doesn't show up useful details?

Comment: Added above.  I don't see any useful info.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html), the default port is 3306. You do have it shown there - might it be the port you're looking for?

Comment: I should have said - this odyssey started when I couldn't connect remotely on 3306.  I know my IP is whitelisted and I can connect because of that to phpMyAdmin but I am trying to get the ODBC connector set up.

Comment: @jerrygarciuh : phpMyAdmin running on the same server as the database?  If so, access to that means nothing.  Try telneting to port 3306 from the database machine and the remote system, and I'm guessing you'll find there's a host-based firewall blocking you.  If you really need this and the sysadmin's still not around, you can always set up an SSH tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use nmap to scan the open ports.

```
nmap -v localhost
```

or with additional options if needed.